# OpenCV C++, find the equation describing the shape of an object

Tags: c++, opencv, computer-vision, video-tracking

[Thresholded Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z4v6E.jpg)

[BGR Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gagbc.jpg)

[Fitted Thresholded Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nePUS.jpg)

Hi all. I'm working on a project about computer vision using OpenCV for C++ interface. My purpose is to track a moving deformable object that is marked with a colored tape. By processing each frame of the video I'm able to effectively isolate the color (as you can see in the thresholded image) and track its trajectory, movement and shape into the BGR image.
My problem is that I need to extrapolate an equation or polynomial that can describe the current shape assumed by my tracked object.
Is there an effective way to do this? I've no idea on how to address the problem.

Thanks in advance,

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your final goal is to detect your shape in various forms i think you want to read about Active shape model: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_shape_model

If you just want to get a polynomial fit of the shape in each instance of time i would use the suggestion of Cherkesgiller Tural and read about 2D curve fitting.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've added a new image so maybe I can explain in a better way what I'd like to do. Basically, I'd like something that constantly maps the shape of my object from a mathematical point of view, something that returns me the equation of a curve (I draw a red curve in the fitted thresholde Image just to be more explicative) the describes the shape assumed by my tracked object.

Comment: So you should look at the second option in my answer the 2d curve fitting. For a c++ libary for curve fitting look at http://www.alglib.net/interpolation/leastsquares.php

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly:

I would start to fit a polygon on your shape. A common method for that is [alpha-shapes](https://anitagraser.com/2011/09/25/a-closer-look-at-alpha-shapes-in-pgrouting/).

You can also try an optimization approach which is enormously powerful because you can basically design your cost-function and constrains however you want. But it is computationally very costly (depending on the algorithm).

Have a look at this [thread](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/14619/are-there-well-known-algorithms-for-fitting-a-polygon-to-an-arbitrary-shape): It might help you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've added a new image so maybe I can explain in a better way what I'd like to do. Basically, I'd like something that constantly maps the shape of my object from a mathematical point of view, something that returns me the equation of a curve (I draw a red curve in the fitted thresholde Image just to be more explicative) the describes the shape assumed by my tracked object.